# Tomcat Connection Pool Monitoring

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Is there any alert mechanism possible in tomcat connection pool ? 
If the max connection pool size is 50 , and if the current count reaches 40 , we need to have an alert so that appropriate action can be taken ( may be some long running txn has to be killed etc ) .

Is such an alert mechanism available out of the box ?

Thanks

Lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use tomcat-jdbc connection pool in production and there isn't such a feature out of the box. It exposes a JMX mbean for monitoring.

You could write custom code or use libraries like [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans) that could periodically export jmx metrics to your monitoring alert server. For e.g. we use riemann for this.